# What is use of SequenceFileInputFilter.Filter in Hadoop

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop2

I can see **SequenceFileInputFilter.Filter** has accept method, which return Boolean, here we can put check on current processing key, if current processing key is not of our interest, we can skip that line from processing.

As far I know, while reading sequence file, hadoop get mapper input key class information from sequence file its self(some meta data about class).
so is it possible that one sequence file have different type of key class,
If its not possible, then what would be real time use of Filter class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding about it is goes like this:

As we can create Mapper class with custom key as below:

```
DerivedMapper extends Mapper<InCustomKey, Text, OutCustomKey, Text>
```

and map method would be

```
public void map(InCustomKey key, Text value, Context contx)
```

So SequencefileReader will read the key's class from metadata present in file,
and create Object using that information, which will be pass to map method. **There could be two reason for implementing Filter**

1. To make code more robust, if Sequence file has different Key class from Mapper's input key class, in that case it would throw some Runtime exception
2. If we are passing directory as a input, there could be possibility that, some of the files have different key in Sequences file.

   In both above mentioned cases, we can leverage the functionality of filter to skip the processing such records.